# Get the Container Model in template MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any way of getting the container model when in an editor/display template?

ModelMetaData has ContainerType, but not the container...

Comment: I can pass it in with additionalValues, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169170/asp-net-mvc-pass-additional-viewdata-to-a-strongly-typed-partial-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169170/asp-net-mvc-pass-additional-viewdata-to-a-strongly-typed-partial-view)

but it would be good if this was just available :)