# Pass variables to a partial view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

How can I send variables to my partial view?

And I don't mean like my model, but values seperate from that

So instead of `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Test/_Partial.cshtml", Model)`

It would be something like `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Test/_Partial.cshtml", Variable = 2)`

And then in my partial view I could just use it like

```
// html
@Variable
// html
```

Comment: You could just use `@Html.Partial("MyPartial", "MyVariable")` and in the partial `@model string`, but a better solution would be to use a child action that returns the partial, and pass a variable to the method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass Additional ViewData to a Strongly-Typed Partial View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169170/pass-additional-viewdata-to-a-strongly-typed-partial-view)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the model of your partial the type you want to pass to it:

```
@model int
```

In the parent view:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Test/_Partial.cshtml", 2)
```

Then access it from the partial view as `@Model`.

Answer (score -1):

Following are the available options to pass data from a Controller to View in ASP.NET MVC which would be appropriate in your case:

- ViewBag
- ViewData
- TempData

*If we want to maintain state between a Controller and corresponding View*- **ViewData and ViewBag are the available options but both of these options are limited to a single server call** (meaning it’s value will be null if a redirect occurs). But if we need to maintain state from one Controller to another (redirect case), then `TempData` is the other available option which will be cleared once hit.

```
public ActionResult Index()
         {
                     ViewBag.EmployeeName = “Tushar Gupta”;
                     return View();
         }
```

**View**

```
<b>Employee Name:</b> @ViewBag.EmployeeName<br />
```